# How to create a blur / shadow in raphael 2.X?

Tags: javascript, raphael, blur

I was wondering if there's a way to create a blur in raphael.

I've had a google around and looked on stack overflow but all of the solutions lead to 404's on github and/or are for a outdated version of raphael.

Does anyone know of a current way of adding blurs and shadows to raphael?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you as well: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.glow

```
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas'), 500, 500);

var circle = paper.circle(100, 100, 80);
circle.attr({
    fill: "#f00"
});
circle.glow({
    offsetx: 2,
    offsety: 2
});​
```